# Vitamio VideoView bad quality in dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, vitamio

I've made vitamio VideoView in Dialog, but quality is very bad, worse than in activity.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

I've added:

```
 mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_HIGH);
 mVideoVIew.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888);
```

Everything works fine now!

Comment: my vitamio player is less smooth than mx player though... any idea how to improve it?